# Can you recommend a good replacement for Windows Sound Recorder?

Tags: windows-xp, software-rec, audio-recording

Can anyone recommend a good, free replacement for Windows 'Sound Recorder'?

Requirements:

- Very quick to load and run
- Allows saving to a compact sound format (e.g. MP3)
- Allows long recordings (1+ Hours)
- Free
- Runs on Windows XP

Would be nice but probably not essential:

- Saves along the way (in case of crashes)
- Allows simple edits (trim start and end and maybe remove chunks in the middle)

Before anyone suggests it, I'm aware of (and have used) Audacity but I'm really after something as simple and lightweight as possible.

Answer (score 15):

[**Audacity®**](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) - free, open source software for recording and editing sounds.

Main Features:

```
* Record live audio.
* Convert tapes and records into digital recordings or CDs.
* Edit Ogg Vorbis, MP3, WAV or AIFF sound files.
* Cut, copy, splice or mix sounds together.
* Change the speed or pitch of a recording.
```

[image]

Note: Audacity requires **[LAME MP3 Encoder](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/Lame_Encoder.htm)** for MP3 output.

Comment: Just saying: "Before anyone suggests it, I'm aware of (and have used) Audacity but I'm really after something as simple and lightweight as possible." -andygrunt

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but did you read the whole of my question? I already rejected Audacity.

Comment: well, there isn't really anything nearly as good as Audacity. i don't know whether Wavepad is still free or not. you might find it easier to use than Audacity. but you better have a darn good uninstaller in place before you put Wavepad on your PC.

Answer (score 4):

Here some freebies from download.com and softpedia (no editors, just recorders):

**[Easy MP3 Sound Recorder](http://download.cnet.com/Free-Easy-MP3-Sound-Recorder/3000-2170_4-10547650.html)**, makes a complete recording studio of your computer. With the recorder you can Capture audio from selected audio device. Capture audio to Wave, WMA, MP3 file format. Capture audio from selected audio input pin. For example, Line In, Microphone, Stereo Mix, Mono Mix, Aux, Video, CD Audio, Phone Line.

[image]

**[Sonarca Sound Recorder Free](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Audio/Audio-Editors-Recorders/Sonarca-Sound-Recorder-Free.shtml)**

[image]

- Supports multiple sound input, audio/video files playback, CD player, line in, microphone, internet radio, even the obsolete tape/VHS cassette or anything else.
- Record various sound input to WAV and MP3.
- CD quality sound recording.
- It uses latest Lame MP3 encoder which is generally believed as the the best MP3 encoder in the world.
- On-the-fly recording, no temporary file generated.
- Intuitive output file management.
- Diagnose and print detailed sound device info.
- Supports majority of modern sound cards: multi channel/professional/external USB sound cards.
- Supports several sound cards at the same system.
- All events are logged for future diagnosis.

**[Free MP3 Sound Recorder](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Audio/Audio-Editors-Recorders/Free-MP3-Sound-Recorder.shtml)**

[image]

- Record sound from many sources such as Microphone, Line-In, Internet Streaming Audio, and any Audio Player program.
- Can work directly with sound card to record anything you hear from your computer.
- Save output audio in MP3, WAV, OGG, VOX audio formats. Can choose output audio's frequency, bitrate, channel and quality.
- Easy-to-use and user-friendly interface.

Comment: This is a nice selection. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 0):

It's what you are looking for.

http://www.freesoundrecorder.net