# What is a free and simple sound editor for Windows?

Tags: software-rec, sound-editing

I'm looking for a (free) sound editor to install on a Vista laptop.

Nothing fancy, just need to take some short sound segments and loop/splice them (converting 10 second recordings into hours) to provide test input for some sound processing software on an iPhone.  Single track, not "hi-fi", no need for weird sound effects, etc.

Emphasis would be on Vista compatibility, ease of installation, overall simplicity, and robustness.

Comment: Related: [Can you recommend a good replacement for Windows Sound Recorder?](http://superuser.com/questions/39779/can-you-recommend-a-good-replacement-for-windows-sound-recorder)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), which can do [looping](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Looping) and [splicing](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/help/faq?s=editing&i=join). Refer to the Audacity [Wiki](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Audacity_Wiki_Home_Page) Homepage for any help.

[image]

Comment: I'm a little leery of Audacity because the "release" level doesn't run on Vista (close as I can tell), so I'd have to use the beta.

Comment: I've run the standard release on Vista without issues, so far at least - I have yet to try anything complicated with the Vista system.

Comment: OK, it seems to run fairly well -- A few flaky things here and there but pretty solid all-in-all.

Answer (score 2):

As Jay wrote, Audacity is free, open source and powerful. Personally, I find the interface in [Goldwave](http://goldwave.com) to be simpler, more intuitive and user-friendly. The evaluation version is free.

[image]

You might also find some useful tools at NCH Software's [Audio tools page](http://www.nch.com.au/software/audio.html) (including another audio editor - WavePad). Some are free and some are for sale. I find their software to be very competently done. However, you should verify the feature set meets your needs before you buy anything - even their commercial products are available for free evaluation - some continue to work after the evaluation period with a reduced feature set.

[image]

Comment: A warning about NCH. The last time I installed one of their trialware programs, it hijacked the search engine and added a toolbar to all my browsers. I still like some of their stuff - but approach with caution!

Answer (score 1):

[Sony Acid Xpress](http://www.acidplanet.com/downloads/xpress/) can do this.

[image]

Just drop your clips on the timeline and drag them out to the desired length. Acid will take care of the looping for you.

Comment: I've been using the "free" version of Acid for awhile, and finding it pretty awkward and non-intuitive.  I think I'll try Audacity next.

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Well, the repeating pop-up ads for the paid version are the first problem -- not subtle at all.  And the free version is pretty badly crippled.  But I found simple editing to be incredibly awkward.  (Don't yet know if Audacity will be better -- just getting going with it.)

Comment: Audacity was much better.

Answer (score 1):

I was a longtime user of audacity. But recently I switched to [WaveShop](http://waveshop.sourceforge.net/download.html).

- It's a bit simpler to use ([No project, No mp3 export needed](https://superuser.com/questions/730629/audacity-save-just-a-sound-file-not-a-project))
- Not so overloaded with features as Audacity is. That's maybe a matter of taste
- Portable

In WaveShop, you simple use [CTRL+C and CTRL+V](http://waveshop.sourceforge.net/Help/Edit_menu/Copy.htm) to repeat sound segments and create loops.

[image]