# Audacity: save just a sound file, not a Project

Tags: audio, file-management, audacity

I commonly use Audacity to make simple edits to a single sound file: trim, filter, fade-in, a few edits, etc.  Just one file.  Not a full-blown "project" in audacity-speak.

Can I then just "file/save" like with a word processor or text editor, instead of performing the following ritual?

- file/export
- re-select filename
- *yes,* you infernal spawn of a Redmond paperclip, I *want* to replace the file
- ignore form to enter metadata
- at last, hit enter
- (and, when quitting Audacity, overruling the prompt to save the changes that I just saved)

Or is there a lightweight tool better suited to such tasks, on either Windows or Linux?

(I use Audacity 2.0.0 on Ubuntu 12, if it matters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or is there a lightweight tool better suited to such tasks, on either Windows or Linux?

On Windows, there is [WaveShop](http://waveshop.sourceforge.net/download.html). It's similar to Audacity and the save process is shorter with 3 clicks:

1. Close WaveShop via X

   - Prompt to save pops up
2. Click Yes

   - Prompt for MP3 quality settings pops up (don't change anything)
3. Click yes

   - WaveShop automatically saves it as mp3 and overwrites the original

[Tadaa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0wZToT3WqE)

---

The GUI is not the best looking one and there aren't as much options as Audacity has. So it's a bit more lightweight (7 MB vs 24 MB)

[[image]

<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZirT.png)

Comment: With a few dozen file formats and a hundred-odd LADSPA plugins, WaveShop has nothing to apologize about.

Answer (score 4):

In Audacity, you can set keyboard shortcut to Export command (this will save you time opening file menu and hitting Export...)
Also you can deselect the option "Show Metadata Editor prior to export step" in Preferences.
This will make it a bit less painful (sorry for my sarcasm)

Comment: Ah, _there_ it is.  Edit, Preferences, Import/Export, When exporting, checkbox "Show metadata editor."  Thanks, that helps.